# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.7+

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I want to use some Google services in my application, so I have added this line to the `.gradle` file: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.7+`. But after trying to sync the project I got this error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.7+
```

**I checked all the available answers on Stackoverflow**. They suggest installing the sdk for `Google repository` and `Google play services` and I did that. Here is a screenshot of the sdks installed on my computer:

[image]

Here is the gradle file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.android.eyedetection"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/localization/LocalizedFormats_fr.properties'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:opencv')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.7+'
   compile files ('libs/commons-math-2.2.jar')
   compile files ('libs/commons-math-2.2-javadoc.jar')
    compile files ('libs/commons-math-2.2-sources.jar')
}
```

I tried to remove the `+`, but that didn't solve it.

How can I solve the problem?

**EDIT:** As suggested by **Stanojkovic** and **Gabriele Mariotti** using 8.4 solves the problem, this is because I was mistakenly trying to use 8.7 which is not released yet. Thanks all.

Comment: Do you want to set Google Cloud Messaging?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, I want to use Mobile Vision API to detect facial landmarks. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try with com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0

Comment: Then also remember to clean your project after adding the dependency

Comment: What is the version of Android Studio?

Comment: @Stanojkovic that solved it! thanks a lot. You may post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: 7.8 or 8.7? In your script you are using 8.7

Comment: @Eenvincible, thanks, it worked by using 8.4. I use version 1.5.1.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, sorry for that, it should be 8.7, I will update the question.

Comment: Glad to help, you are wellcome.

Comment: It is the real problem. 8.7 doesn't exist!

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks a lot for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue depends by

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.7+'
```

This version **is not published yet** (the apk is still in rollout, but the library is not public in the IDE)

Use the last stable release:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```